# NVD3 - Show all tick values

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

My chart needs to have tick values in multiples of 3. For example, if I have 5 data points, my x-axis should show (3, 6, 9, 12, 15). How do I get nvd3 to display all tick numbers? I pasted my code below for reference

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
.options({
  margin: {left: 100, bottom: 100},
  x: function(d,i) { return i*3},
  showXAxis: true,
  showYAxis: true,
  showLegend: true,
  reduceXTicks: false,
  showMaxMin: false,
  //values: $scope.data.values.map( function(d,i) { return i*3; }),
  useInteractiveGuideline: true,
  transitionDuration: 2500,
  showControls : true
})
;


chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
  .axisLabel('Ager')
  .orient('bottom')
  //.tickValues( function(d,i) { return i*3;})
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
  .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
  .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));     nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

I've tried everything I can think of and read online to get nvd3 show all ticks in multiples of 3. Please help me out of this tricky situation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could have read the d3 docs and see that `.tickValues` does not accept a function.

Construct the array of tick values based on the domain of the x-axis. Because the domain is not yet set you have to construct it yourself based on the data.

Using the SinCos example from the nvd3 site

```
var myData = sinAndCos();
var xExtent = d3.extent(myData[0].values, d=>d.x);
xExtent = [Math.floor(xExtent[0]), Math.ceil(xExtent[1])+1];
var xTicks = d3.range(xExtent[0], xExtent[1]).filter(n => n%3===0);

chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
    .tickValues(xTicks)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));
```

Complete example. It will not run directly from the browser (will not load nvd3 inside an iframe(??)). Copy it to a local file and run it from there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link href="https://nvd3.org/assets/css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://nvd3.org/assets/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="https://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart">
<svg style="width:800px;height:500px;"></svg>
</div>
<script>
/*These lines are all chart setup.  Pick and choose which chart features you want to utilize. */
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .margin({left: 100})  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
                .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
                .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
                .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
                .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
  ;
  var myData = sinAndCos();
  var xExtent = d3.extent(myData[0].values, d=>d.x);
  xExtent = [Math.floor(xExtent[0]), Math.ceil(xExtent[1])+1];
  var xTicks = d3.range(xExtent[0], xExtent[1]).filter(n => n%3===0);

  chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
      .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
      .tickValues(xTicks)
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

  chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
      .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
      .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.   
      .datum(myData)         //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
      .call(chart);          //Finally, render the chart!

  //Update the chart when window resizes.
  nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update() });
  return chart;
});
/**************************************
 * Simple test data generator
 */
function sinAndCos() {
  var sin = [],sin2 = [],
      cos = [];

  //Data is represented as an array of {x,y} pairs.
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10)});
    sin2.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10) *0.25 + 0.5});
    cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
  }

  //Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
  return [
    {
      values: sin,      //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
      key: 'Sine Wave', //key  - the name of the series.
      color: '#ff7f0e'  //color - optional: choose your own line color.
    },
    {
      values: cos,
      key: 'Cosine Wave',
      color: '#2ca02c'
    },
    {
      values: sin2,
      key: 'Another sine wave',
      color: '#7777ff',
      area: true      //area - set to true if you want this line to turn into a filled area chart.
    }
  ];
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out based on your answer (Newbie here) but I finally did it. Thank you so much for the prompt response. Sorry it took me a few days to reply back. I was learning more about D3 usage while using your answer.